# Building a local database using python and unable to proceed due to "key errors" (full code below)

Tags: python, pandas, class, keyerror

So I've been working on my python code to create a simple database of students and the universities that they're studying in using classes and the pandas library. It goes like this -

1. I'm trying to create a database where the user can input his/her college details including the courses to an already made csv file (works perfectly)
2. I'm trying to add a function to delete the whole row of details (id, college name, college course, college city, fees and pincode) when the user enters the 'id' of the college from the csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from csv import writer

def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    # Open file in append mode
    with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
        # Create a writer object from csv module
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file
        csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)

class College:
    def __init__(self, collegeId, collegeName, courseType, city, fees, pinCode):
        self.collegeId = collegeId
        self.collegeName = collegeName
        self.courseType = courseType
        self.city = city
        self.fees = fees
        self.pinCode = pinCode
        
#The @classmethod decorator exists so you can create class methods that are passed to the actual class object within the function call
    @classmethod
    def student(self):
        collegeId = str(input("Enter college ID: "))
        collegeName = str(input("Enter college's name: "))
        courseType = str(input("Enter course: "))
        city = str(input("Enter city: "))
        fees = str(input("Enter fees: "))
        pinCode = str(input("Enter pincode: "))

        cond = str(input("Would you like to delete any entry? Type Yes or No: "))
        if cond in ['yes', 'Yes', 'YES', 'Y', 'y']:
            df = pd.read_csv('colleges.csv')
            df = df.dropna(how = 'all') #filtering rows that don't have any data
            df = df.set_index('identity')
            delete_row = input("please enter the id of the college whose data needs to be deleted: ")
            df.drop(df[df['identity'] == delete_row].index, inplace = True)
        elif cond in ['no', 'No', 'NO', 'N', 'n']:
            row_contents = [] #empty list initiation
            row_contents.append(collegeId)
            row_contents.append(collegeName)
            row_contents.append(courseType)
            row_contents.append(city)
            row_contents.append(fees)
            row_contents.append(pinCode)
            append_list_as_row('colleges.csv', row_contents)
        else:
            print("invalid entry. Please reply with a Yes or No.")
        return self(collegeId, collegeName, courseType, city, fees, pinCode)


data = College.student()
print(data)
```

On line 36, I get an error -

```
KeyError: 'identity'
```

Need a little support with the deletion of row part because I've been stuck for hours. I'm a newbie.

Also here's the csv file's format -

```
 Identity, cname, course, city, fees, pincode
```

Comment: Why are you mixing the `csv` module with `pandas`? Either work with `csv` and lists-of-dicts, or `pandas` dataframes.

Comment: @AKX is that what's causing the error?